# play video in single cell in collection view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, avplayer

I have problem with playing video in the collection view cell in single cell

cell can have both video and images, when its video the video is downloaded and played from local directory

collection View has 2 cells in each row

problem is : i want video to play in only 1 cell at a time and stop when that video is no more visible

I used following code in cell for item at index path.

```
let localVideoURL = getDownloadedVideoPathFromDocumentDirectory(filename: eachTimeLineFeed.mediaFile!)
    print("Play Video from URL \(localVideoURL)")

        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: localVideoURL!);
        self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item);
        self.avPlayer?.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        self.avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.avPlayer);

        self.avPlayerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        self.avPlayerLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: SCREENWIDTH()/2, height: SCREENWIDTH()/2)
        cell.viewVideo.layer.addSublayer(self.avPlayerLayer!)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerItemDidReachEnd), name: NOTIFICATION_PLAYER_DID_END_PLAYING_VIDEO, object: self.avPlayer?.currentItem!)
        self.avPlayer?.play()
```

Comment: what problem you have in the above question?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing now ?

Comment: cells which are visible, and all have videos , all of them are played and even if i scroll down the video is not stopped.

Comment: which class do you have this code in

Comment: this code is in cellforitem delegate. @shubh

Comment: @downvoters, if you think its an irrevelant or an easy question to ask, you can show some well being and answer rather than downvoting.

Comment: please follow the below answer, it tells the correct approach. Those cells which have now moved of the screen should have the video player stopped - something your code does not do at this moment.

Answer (score 2):

Add collectionview optional delegates to your viewcontroller [collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618006-collectionview) and inside this function you can reach indexpath, cell and collection view. Then you can stop playing video on cell item.

Swift

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell,
                    forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

Objective-C

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```